# JsonSerializationSettingsException was unhandled

Tags: c#, json, serialization, twitter, tweetsharp

I'm trying to get tweets at the homepage of twitter. But, JsonSerializationSettingsException is thrown:

*Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'TweetSharp.TwitterStatus' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
Path '', line 1, position 1.*

```
  listBox1.Items.Clear();
        var option = new ListTweetsOnHomeTimelineOptions() { Count = 25, IncludeEntities = false };
        var tweets = service.ListTweetsOnHomeTimeline(option);
        foreach (var i in tweets)
        {
            string tweet = String.Format("{0} -> {1}", i.User.ScreenName, i.Text);
            listBox1.Items.Add(tweet);
        }
```

Comment: What is the object that you are deserializing to?

Comment: We will need to see both the JSON you are trying to deserialize as well as the class that you are trying to deserialize into.  This error is almost always caused by the two not matching up.  Specifically, one has an array and the other does not.